# TokBox API video resolution issue in iOS app

Tags: ios, video, resolution, opentok, tokbox

I have been trying to post video to server:

```
_capturePreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh;
[[self class] dimensionsForCapturePreset:_capturePreset
                                   width:&_captureWidth
                                  height:&_captureHeight];
_capture_queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.tokbox.OTVideoCapture",
                                               DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
_videoFrame = [[OTVideoFrame alloc] initWithFormat:[OTVideoFormat videoFormatNV12WithWidth:screenWidth
                                                        height:screenHeight]];
```

I wanted to capture screen resolution as same as when a video is recorded on device but it is returning 640*480 always. Can tell how to set desired resolution for recording and archiving video from the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Composed archives have a fixed dimension of VGA (640x480). If you prefer to capture the full published resolution, consider evaluating individual stream archiving.

Please refer this link for details.
https://support.tokbox.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206241666-Archived-video-resolution-is-supposed-to-be-720x1280-but-reports-as-640x480